# Not able to download rest-0.8.zip from http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo

Tags: grails

Grails is not able to download rest-0.8.zip from http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo. This is my BuildConfig.groovy. Guess i have configured the repositories rite

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.offline.mode=false
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}.war"

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    inherits("global") {
        // uncomment to disable ehcache
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve

    repositories {
        inherits true  // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins
        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/"
}
    dependencies {
                compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'
        compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6'

    }

    plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":jquery:1.7.1"
        runtime ":resources:1.1.6"
                compile ":spring-security-core:1.2.7.3"
                compile ":spring-security-mock:1.0.1"
                compile ":spring-security-ldap:1.0.6"
                compile ":joda-time:1.4"
                compile ":cache-headers:1.1.5"
                build ":rest:0.8"
                test ":code-coverage:1.2.5"
        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
    }
}
```

But rest-0.8.zip is not downloaded

```
==== grailsCentral: tried
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-rest/tags/RELEASE_0.8/grails-rest-0.8.zip
    ==== mavenCentral: tried
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/rest/0.8/rest-0.8.zip
    ==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/: tried
      http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/org/grails/plugins/rest/0.8/rest-0.8.zip
    ==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins: tried
      http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/rest/0.8/rest-0.8.zip
            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
            ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
            :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
            :: org.grails.plugins#rest;0.8!rest.zip
            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Any idea where am i going wrong?

Comment: Getting 401 Unauthorized exception. `HTTP response status: 401 url=http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/org/grails/plugins/rest/0.8/rest-0.8.zip
CLIENT ERROR: Unauthorized url=http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/org/grails/plugins/rest/0.8/rest-0.8.zip` What authentication is needed for this?

Comment: Can you go to the web address from your browser? It should download a zip file.

Comment: Yes Nathan, i was able too. Anyways, Cleared the proxy and it worked :) . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you have declared build for the plugin. Try changing the dependencies portion to follow the REST plugin documentation and declare `compile`

```
plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":jquery:1.7.1"
        runtime ":resources:1.1.6"
                compile ":spring-security-core:1.2.7.3"
                compile ":spring-security-mock:1.0.1"
                compile ":spring-security-ldap:1.0.6"
                compile ":joda-time:1.4"
                compile ":cache-headers:1.1.5"
                //changed to compile from build
                compile ":rest:0.8"
                test ":code-coverage:1.2.5"
        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
    }
```

Comment: It was compile. My bad, had modified just before posting. Thank you

Comment: Glad you solved the issue. If it really was compile accept my answer and let those who follow know.